# Acces local variables inside .timpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if something
  interval = 5
else
  interval = 15

time_input = #something
$(time_input).timepicker
  minutes: { interval: interval }
```

I am trying to access the local variable inside the timepicker function... ....................
What will be the best possible way to do it...

Comment: What's a timpicker?

Comment: its a timepicker http://asaex.org/FORO/templates/common/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker.html